# How to write linux app/library to interact with Samsung Galaxy Buds headphones?

Tags: linux, headphones

I'd like to write some library/app to interact with Galaxy Buds.
I assume that this would require me to somehow sniff packages it sends to my mobile telephone and get which corresponds to what command(volume/pause/play) and so on. And then write some wrapper for it? I'd like to make this app/library reusable between different Linux distros, and not-that-hard-portable to Mac OS.

Knowing all that I still in the place where I'm not sure where to start from.
I'd appreciate suggestions to any part of this process e.g (Programming language selection, software for BT sniffing ...)

I do have some experience with C#/Java/C++, but I'm willing to learn if these aren't most suitable for solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that much about the libraries needed for such a solution, but as far as sniffing is concerned, I know that Wireshark ([WireShark_Bluetooth_Sniffing](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth)) is a good starting place.Once you isolate the touch commands, I assume you can map them to media commands, as described here: [D-Bus_Media_Commands](https://askubuntu.com/a/1068716)